# Cannot activate num pad at all

Tags: gnome, numpad

I have two accounts on the same machine. Num pad on one account it working normally e.g. I can turn it ON/OFF via `NumLock` button.

The num pad on the other account on this machine stopped working. I cannot turn it on and the buttons work as the NumLock is turned off.

This happened without me touching any setting or all. It just happened and now I cannot turn them on no matter what I try. I tried via console command `numlockx on` - did not help. Tried via UI setting - did not help either. Updated the system from 11.10 to 12.04, did not help either.

I really do not know what to do except I make a clean reinstallation of the system which would take 2 days away from me. It's obviously the problem in this account only, as num pad works in the other account.

Anyone with a good suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with:

**Universal Access -> Pointing and Clicking -> Mouse Keys -> Off**

Answer (score 1):

I finally got the answer from my searches: System Settings → Keyboard Layouts → Options → Use keyboard LED to show alternative layouts → and here just unmark Num Lock.