# How do you enable PointerButtons to work on the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, customization

Let's assume I have added the following keyboard map in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/us`.  Why can't use the the keyboard key as a Pointer Button.

```
partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "alt-intl" {
  name[Group1]= "English (US, alternative international)";
  include "us"
  key <AB04> { [ Pointer_Button1 ]};
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the settings option you need to enable the **Mouse Keys** under

**All Settings->Universal Access->Pointing And Clicking**

The setting is also described at the following [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162299/cannot-activate-num-pad-at-all/162313#162313).